# WPF DataGrid 'Select All Button' followed by Control-C

Tags: wpf

Right after loading a WPF DataGrid, I hit the 'Select All Button' (upper left hand corner) followed by Control-C.

But this sequence does not copy the datagrid items to my clipboard.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems data grid does not focus itself when that button is clicked, so you have to fix it yourself:

```
dataGrid.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.SelectAll, OnDataGridSelectAll));
```

And then:

```
private void OnDataGridSelectAll(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    grid.Focus();
    grid.SelectAll();
}
```

You can also add command binding in xaml if you want so.